# Repeated MapThread to create a list from three other lists

Tags: list-manipulation

We have three lists:

```
list1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}; list2 = {q, w, e}; list3 = {h,j,k};
```

We want to have

```
desired={{{a, b},q,h}, {{c, d},w,j}, {{e, f},e,k}}};
```

For this goal, we created `list6` by

```
list6 = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {list2, list3}];
```

of course `Transpose[{list2, list3}]` has the same result; We used

```
desired=MapThread[{#1, Flatten@#2} &, {list1, list6}];
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: `{list1, list2, list3}\[Transpose]`?

Comment: Why not just 'Thread[{list1, list2, list3}]'?

Comment: They are amazing answers!!

Comment: You can still use `MapThread`: `MapThread[{#1, #2, #3} &, {list1, list2, list3}]` or `MapThread[{##} &, {list1, list2, list3}]` or `MapThread[List, {list1, list2, list3}]`. `MapThread` is more general than just choosing from two lists: you can choose from any number of lists. But for this application, using `Transpose` or `Thread` is the best way to do this.

Comment: @ march, from the help of Mathematica I interpreted that just for two lists it is possible. The job of MapThread is enjoyable!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
Thread@{list1, list2, list3}
```

> {{{a, b}, q, h}, {{c, d}, w, j}, {{e, f}, e, k}}